# ChangeTracker Properties have CurrentValue of -2147482646 but IsTemporary is false

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

We have an application using EF Core. We are using the ChangeTracker to build a basic auditing system to log changes to the database.

It is picking up changes correctly, and logging the correct database generated primary keys etc as we are using property.IsTemporary to check for temporary values and then pick those up after the SaveChanges.

When an entity is added via a navigation property, for example customer.Transactions.Add(new Transaction())... then the CustomerId property is not marked as temporary but has a value of -2147482646 or -2147482647 resulting in the wrong value being saved to the audit

I have already tried adding a check for KeyValues with the value of -2147482646 or -2147482647 but some times this value is different and doesn't catch all cases. I can't understand why IsTemporary isn't being set if it is in fact a temporary value.

Ideally we want something were we can call property.IsTemporary or property.IsForeignKey so we can then pickup those values and audit the correct value after calling SaveChangesAsync().

```
public bool OnAfterSavingChanges()
{
    if (TableActivityEvents.Count == 0) return false;

    foreach (var tableActivityEvent in TableActivityEvents)
    {
        // Get the final value of any Temporary Properties
        foreach (var property in tableActivityEvent.TemporaryProperties)
            if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                tableActivityEvent.KeyValues[property.Metadata.Name] = property.CurrentValue;
            else
                tableActivityEvent.NewValues[property.Metadata.Name] = property.CurrentValue;

        DbContext.TableActivityLogs.Add(tableActivityEvent.ToActivityLog());
    }

    return true;
}

public void OnBeforeSavingChanges()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        if (entry.Entity is TableActivityLog || entry.State == EntityState.Detached || entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
            continue;

        var tableActivityEvent = new TableActivityEvent(entry, AdminUserGuid);
        TableActivityEvents.Add(tableActivityEvent);

        foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
        {
            if (property.IsTemporary || (property.CurrentValue != null && property.CurrentValue.Equals(-2147482646)))
            {
                // Value will be generated by the database, so this needs to be picked up after saving
                tableActivityEvent.TemporaryProperties.Add(property);
                continue;
            }

            string propertyName = property.Metadata.Name;
            if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
            {
                tableActivityEvent.KeyValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                continue;
            }

            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    tableActivityEvent.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    tableActivityEvent.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    if (property.IsModified)
                    {
                        tableActivityEvent.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                        tableActivityEvent.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (var tableActivityEvent in TableActivityEvents.Where(_ => !_.HasTemporaryProperties))
        DbContext.TableActivityLogs.Add(tableActivityEvent.ToActivityLog());

    TableActivityEvents.RemoveAll(_ => !_.HasTemporaryProperties);
}
```

I would expect that Entities added via Navigation Properties should still be logged with the correct value when it is picked up after a SaveChangesAsync. We just need a reliable way to identify that it is, in fact, a temporary value.

Comment: Can you provide a sample repro? I can't seem to reproduce it (EF Core 2.2.6 is that matters) - `IsTemporary` for FK matches the `IsTemporary` of the principal PK.

Comment: I managed to track it down to one specific instance in my code causing the issue. I created a new entity for Customer, and then created a new entity for Transaction using customer.CustomerId in the transaction. So the CustomerId hadn't yet been saved, so that means it still had a temporary value. Either way EF Core isn't marking a "temporary" value correctly, but we do have a work around. I will try to make a repo to demonstrate, and maybe I need to put in an issue on GitHub.

Comment: According to [IsTemporary not always properly set](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17700) this was fixed in 3.0